# Small signal analysis of BJT dynamic microphone preamplifier

Tags: bjt, preamp, small-signal

I am trying to do a small signal analysis for the following circuit
[image]

I did not have any experience with BJT so I am having a hard time to analyze the circuit. From research, I know Q1 is common base and Q2 and Q3 are common emitter. To draw the small signal model, I would have to short all DC source and capacitors.

Then I ended up with the following circuit
[image]

I am not sure what to do next. I tried to break the circuit into 3 parts to analyze but I am not sure what to do with the 47K, 56K,15K resistors that's connected to Q1.

Can anyone help with the small signal analysis?

Now I have this for the first part if I were to divided the circuit to 3 parts.
[image]

To find the input impedance, applying KCL then it would be
12/47k + gmVpi + Vpi/rpi + Vin/10K?

I am a bit confused with Vpi and rpi. Do I need to calculate that or it's from the BC547 data sheet?

Comment: Why are you using a common base input? what's your Mic impedance?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy no, its common emmiter with shunt feedback

Comment: The 15K and 56K are bias resistors for the base of Q1. In small signal analysis, the base of Q1 is shorted to ground by the 220uF capacitor. The 15K and 56K resistors then become redundant (each end is shorted to ground). It would help if you kept the wire to the base of Q1 to see that. (Short it to ground).

Comment: From my research, this amplifies dynamic microphones with 200 to 600 ohm output impedance, so I guess the mic impedance is between 200-600 ohms?

Comment: @lsi A common base input has a low impedance, ideally you would want the input impedance to be around 1.5K-2K since most mic manufacturers "expect" their mics to be connected to such impedance.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy input is base, output is collector, feedback is through the 3.3M resistor, classic configuration.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Q3 is common collector. (Emitter follower).

Comment: Which 47K resistor are you asking about? There is one between the collector of Q1 and the base of Q2, and there is another between the collector of Q1 and \$V_{CC}\$

Comment: So, Q1 is common base, Q2 is common emitter and Q3 is common collector? I am actually a bit confused with Q2 because seems like the collector and emitter of Q2 is connected to ground to me. But my research said it's CE...

Comment: Yes, each transistor is configured as a different type of amplifier. You are right, Q2 is common emitter. The collector of Q2 is not connected to ground, but through a 10K resistor to Vcc.

Comment: I was thinking if I divided the circuit into 3 parts, then part 1 will be Q1, 10k (connected to the emitter of Q1)will be the input resistance? and I don't know what to do with the 47K(connected to Vcc) and 56K(connected to Vcc). then Q2 can be the second part of the circuit? then I guess the 47K connected to Q2, (I considered that as the input resistance of Q2?)

Comment: Yes, the 10k connected to Q1's emitter is in parallel with the Q1 internal impedance. The 47K connected to Vcc provides current to Q1's collector. The 47K connected to Q2's base is part of an adder with the 3.3M from Q3's emitter. Together, they determine the relative weights given to the signal from Q1's collector and from Q3's emitter, which are combined and fed into Q2's base.

Comment: To do a real small signal analysis, replace the transistors with their hybrid pi models, ( resistors and a controlled current source) and then do a circuit analysis.

Comment: @lsi The first thing I'd want to do is to perform a sanity check on the DC quiescent operating point. The next thing is to know exactly how the microphone itself works. (Too many kinds floating about.) Only then, would I dive into the small signal part. The common-base first stage is DC biased just as any common-emitter stage. In fact, you can see all of the usual culprits -- the base biasing pair, the emitter resistor, and the collector resistor. If you spend a little time working out the DC quiescent point, my interest may climb a bit. Just FYI.

Comment: input stage is indeed very suspect. Not like any mic preamp I have ever seen. If there wasn't a DC block cap I would say it is powering an electret mic, but there is. But a very odd way to try to amplify a dynamic mic.

Answer (score 1):

This common base operates with about 2 volts on the base. Thus Iemitter is 1.3/10K or 130 uA.

The 'reac' is 26 ohms/0.13mA == 150 ohms. Low yes, however.

The frequency response of 100uF (Cin) and 100 ohms is 0.01 second, or 16Hz.

================================

Regarding 'reac'

When first delighting in the use of small_signal analysis, I soon realized I could predict the gain of bipolar devices (FETs were rare, expensive, and not stable in parameters) simply by

- dividing the combined Rs on the collector, in parallel

by

- the series emitter resistances;

And that series emitter resistance (if no discrete external R) was just

- 26 ohms / Re in mA

thus a device operating at 1mA would have

'reac' of 26/1 = 26 ohms

And if that bipolar has a 260 ohm collector resistor, with only scope probe as the load, then the voltage gain was precisely

- Gain = Rcollector / Remitter = Rcollector / 26 == 260/26 = 10X

And I've in the intervening decades used my personal lable 'reac' for that value, which is the slope of the emitter_base diode.

Another way to compute it is 1/tranconductance.

Again, this value is just the small_signal resistance of emitter_base diode.

Comment: What is reac? input reactance? How is it ohms/Amp ?